# Compiling ShellCode Program in C error

Tags: c, shellcode

I am currently reading through a book about shellcoding and I am running into some issues during one of the examples. I am trying to compile the code below but I keep getting an error about stray "\". Is there a certain way I have to input the characters because of the "\"?

```
// shellcode.c

char shellcode[] =
“\xeb\x1a\x5e\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x8d\x1e\x89\x5e\x08\x89\x46”
“\x0c\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe1”
“\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68”;

int main(){

    int *ret;
    ret = (int *)&ret + 2;
    (*ret) = (int)shellcode;
}
```

Comment: `\x` yields an escaped `x` character.

Answer (score 0):

\x indicates a hexadecimal character escape. From C99 6.4.4.4.:

> The hexadecimal digits that follow the backslash and the letter x in a hexadecimal escape sequence are taken to be part of the construction of a single character for an integer character constant or of a single wide character for a wide character constant.
>
> EXAMPLE 3 Even if eight bits are used for objects that have type char, the construction '\x123' specifies an integer character constant containing only one character, since a hexadecimal escape sequence is terminated only by a non-hexadecimal character. To specify an integer character constant containing the two characters whose values are '\x12' and '3', the construction '\0223' may be used, since an octal escape sequence is terminated after three octal digits. (The value of this two-character integer character constant is implementation-defined.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is caused by the typographic quotes: `“` `”`.

In C, strings must be enclosed by regular double quotes: `"`

The `\x` notation for hex characters only works inside strings (double quotes) and character constants (single qoutes). Becuse of the typographic qoutes the compiler doesn't recognize the code as a string.

So try changing the declaration like this:

```
char shellcode[] =
"\xeb\x1a\x5e\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x8d\x1e\x89\x5e\x08\x89\x46"
"\x0c\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe1"
"\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68";
```

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. I just realized maybe because I pasted the code, it didn't read it as a string right away. One I deleted the quotes and retyped them, then the text turned yellow(nano) to signify a string and it compiled.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated before, your quotes are an issue here. Pasting them on vi produces `?~@~\\xeb..` which may explain the complain about the backslash.

Also, I would consider this cast for shellcode, which is more straightforward.

```
char shellcode[] =
"\xeb\x1a\x5e\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x8d\x1e\x89\x5e\x08\x89\x46"
"\x0c\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe1"
"\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68";

int main(){
        (*(void(*)()) shellcode)();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I just copied and pasted what you had and I am so confused. Not really confused but a bit. Is that a function that was called? Maybe it is confusing because it is all on one line. I am still a novice when it comes to programming but I am working hard on it.

Comment: Well the shellcode is a piece of code, which will ultimately call `exec` system call family. Hence, from the C perspective, this is like a function call. In particular, the function will be `noreturn`. So I find this cast more obvious. For information, I'm not the one inventing this cast.